# Highlight row color based on a cell value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an issue with matplotlib cell color. Below is a simple code which plots a table with help of matplotlib. However, I would like to color the particular rows with red if the value of a number in column 4 is negative. Not getting anywhere, since I can only fill the color of one cell, instead of entire row.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import pandas as pd

columns = ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')
rows = ["A", "B"]
cell_text = [['1348','12','177','-0.12','1.7'],
             ['2315','12','174','-0.05','2.1'],
             ['1147','11','137',' 0.02','2.4'],
             ['1375','11','128',' 0.1','3.4']
             ]

df=pd.DataFrame(cell_text)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('tight')
ax.axis('off')
the_table = ax.table(cellText=df.values,colLabels=columns,loc='center')
i=0
for j, row in df.iterrows():
 
    if (float(df.iloc[j,3]) > 0):
        the_table.get_celld()[(i,j)].set_facecolor("blue")
    else:
        the_table.get_celld()[(i,j)].set_facecolor("green")
    i=i+1
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with matplotlib's tables, but as you can set the color of a cell, setting the color of a row could be done with a simple for loop:

```py
...


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if float(df.iloc[index, 3]) > 0:
        color = "green"
    else:
        color = "red"

    for col in range(df.shape[1]):
        # index + 1 because of headers row
        the_table[index + 1, col].set_facecolor(color)

...
```

[image: the colored table]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `the_table.get_celld()` returns a dict, so you have to iterate over elements in order to color them, as the method `set_facecolor` applies to a cell and not a dict.

```py
for j, row in df.iterrows():
    if float(df.iloc[j, 3]) > 0:
        cells_to_color = [c for (row, col), c in the_table.get_celld().items() if row == i]
        for c in cells_to_color:
            c.set_facecolor("blue")
    else:
        cells_to_color = [c for (row, col), c in the_table.get_celld().items() if row == i]
        for c in cells_to_color:
            c.set_facecolor("green")
    i = i + 1
```